# How to add grid in Magento edit tab?

Tags: php, magento, admin

I ha created a new magento module. It shows info like for example Sales/Orders grid, then on click of order there is edit(in original magento view) tabs. I have created some tabs and I want one of them to be grid, like in orders shipment, creditmemos or invoices. 
How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

It's not really too much different then adding a grid to any other page.  I know when I was building a module I dug into the Google Base addon that is native to Magento, I found a lot of good code there to help me understand how to implement different aspects of an admin module.

For instance my tab block overides grid, like so:

```
class Ssi_Crm_Block_Quotes_Edit_Tab_Bom_Product extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
```

This class then overrides the standard grid functions such as _prepareCollection() and _prepareColumns() stuff that you can find documented elsewhere.